# Submitting form with vanilla Javascript does not contain AngularJS rendered input value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to submit a form with vanilla javascript but the POST request does not contain the input values.

Does it have something to do that AngularJS renders the html with the ng-repeat and sets the name field dynamically ? I know I can do this with pure angularjs but I am just curious why the POST request does not contain user[n] values

```
<form id="form" action="myurl" method="POST">
  <a title="Finalize" onclick="document.forms['form'].submit();"><i class="icon-check-circle"></i></a>
  <span ng-repeat="royalty in royalties track by $index">
    <input class="pull-right" type="checkbox" name="user[{{royalty.user.id}}]" ng-model="royalty.selected" value="1"/>
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: That's tough to answer without seeing the javascript you say is not collecting the data

Comment: `;document.forms['form'].submit();` doesn't need any fancy collection mechanism ..?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, the javascript I was talking about is the onclick content shown above.

Comment: @Teemu why should it need a collection mechanism? It should just send the input elements inside the form tag or not?

Comment: It doesn't need any mechanisms, the comment was rather pointed to Darren ... Why don't you use regular `input type="submit"` ..?

Comment: Yup - didn't see that - my bad - Try changing `id="form"` to `name="form"` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms#Specifications - if you can't then try `document.forms[0]`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yeah it was a mistake to use the id instead of the name but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work as expected:

https://plnkr.co/edit/BPQfx1vSQfug5H0uVyhT?p=preview

```
<form method="post" name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController" action="test.place">
  <input ng-model="val" name="anim"  />
         <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

script

```
document.forms['testForm'].submit()
```

[image]

ngSubmit has an effect on forms but only if they don't have an action present see note in documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: The deciding difference is that on my code the input will be rendered later with ng-repeat filled with data from a http request.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to use an ng-if to dynamically remove/add the input element to see if it matters if it's dynamically added but doesn't seem to cause any problems so hard to say without seeing a reproduction.

Comment: You are right. On your plunkr it works completely fine even if i add ng-repeat in it..